# How we can test selenium codes without doing login again

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cmd, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make a simple code automation. It firstly, needs to login, then perform some action.

When I run the code in eclipse it logs in (i'm solving captcha manually for 3 minutes) then the process should start.

After some changes when I click run, it tries to login again. This happens every time.

But after different attempts to fix it, the login process still takes a long time for me. After x amount of attempts it also causes me to be banned from the site.

So, without login again and again. After every code changes, how can I get my automation to work?

```
E.g: RUN 
1-)go to youtube.com 
2-)login 
3-)go to any song 
4-)get song's name, save
```

I'm making some code changes on 3rd and 4th process, and then i'm clicking RUN. It's starting at 1st step again (login). After clicking run 3-4 times, It causes me to be banned from the site.

> The main question: How can i try 3rd 4th step codes without login
> process again.

I hope you can understand my issue.

Comment: i was trying to do same thing, try to google for "skip login selenium" i got some interesting blogs, but basically there are two approaches, add cookies to selenium in a before test method or use some REST library to make a post request before your test

Comment: How can i try each selenium code through cmd to control browser?
I heard that python and cmd(added selenium library) can control the browser step by step.
e.g: https://imgur.com/qOZ1caI

Comment: i did not understand quite well, but as far as i know you cannot use the cmd as an IDE like pycharm or intellij, the only thing you can do is run/trigger your scripts once you have written them in the IDE.